# Replacing value in colums empties the colums

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I have a column `prix` in my dataframe called `features`. This column is supposed to have three values: `(1, 2, 3)`.
I have the value `4` which is noise. I would like to replace every `4` with `3`.
I did this:

```
# initially string and convert to int
features.prix.astype(int)
# code to replace
features['prix'] = features['prix'].replace('4', '3', inplace=True)
```

But after I run this, `features['prix']` became empty. When I `print(features)`, I have `None` in the columns `Prix`.

Please let me know if i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use parameter `inplace = True` in pandas, the function overwrites your original DataFrame and doesn't return anything (i.e. returns None), so, since you're assigning this result to your `featrues['prix']` column, it gets overwritten with None.

You should choose whether to use inplace or assign result to your column, i.e.:

Either do

```
features['prix'].replace('4','3',inplace=True)
```

or

```
features['prix'] = features['prix'].replace('4','3')
```

Note that `inplace` parameter is now discouraged as they plan to eventually deprecate it, so the second method is now preferred.

Comment: i just tested and it didn't work. Execute without error but 4 is still present

Comment: Oh I just saw you're converting your ['prix'] to int before? You should try replacing int instead of str (i.e. 4, not '4')

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the in-place replacement `features['prix'].replace('4','3',inplace=True)` doesn't return any value, which is why you then see `features['prix']` being `None`.

Removing `features['prix'] =` from the line should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns `None` since `inplace=True` is specified. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html),

> #### Returns: DataFrame or None
>
> Object after replacement or None if `inplace=True`.

In general, the `inplace` parameter allows you control whether the DataFrame is modified "in place" or whether a new value is returned.

To debug your code you can either remove the `inplace` parameter (it defaults to `False`)

```
features['prix'] = features['prix'].replace('4', '3')
```

or do not set `features['prix']` with the output

```
features['prix'].replace('4', '3', inplace=True)
```